# What happens when a query gets very large results

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, bigdata

most usages/tutorial/manuals explain how to use the methods in context of a manageable DB.

So if `User.where( some condition)` would return a result of tens or hundreds it would reasonable to think that Rails/DB/server could handle it

What happens if that same query were to return a result of thousands or hundred of thousands of record? Dare I say million of records?

What does it depend on? What limits are forced by Rails or the hardware (if any)?

And most importantly, is there a way to handle such large data set in Rails (without crashing everything?)

Comment: The best way to handle a large data set is to leave it in the database and do all your work on it inside the database.

Comment: The question is "What do you need to do with million of selected records? Display them to user?"

Comment: Lets say the table in question is coordinates for the model lifetime. If a coordinate is taken every second, so there could be millions of coordinates. If I want to display them I need to fetch each one (lets say I must, and can't use shortcuts)

Comment: @NickGinanto Postgres can handle 1 million objects. But I dont know any interface, that can show 1 m objects to user at the same time. Maybe you need a smaller subset of objects?

Comment: so if the result is more than 1 million the query will fail?

Comment: @NickGinanto Postgres query wont fail. But your application probably will (if you do not build it to handle such queries).

Answer (score 3):

The basic thing is that PostgreSQL will materialize the result set to disk if it gets too large.  This means that you get a speed hit, but it keeps memory free for other operations.

In general there is rarely a need in PostgreSQL to send hundreds of thousands or millions of rows to a client ever.  The key is to build your queries (and with proper SQL extensions as needed) to return only the data your front-end needs, properly aggregated etc. in the database.  I have met a number of people who think that putting such aggregation logic in the db slows it down (and there is a CPU time cost) but the costs in that area tend to be well-repaid many times over in disk I/O wait time costs and the like.

The fundamental question I would ask is "why do you need to see millions of records?"  You are basically saying you want to keep these in memory or store them on disk, then transfer them across the network, then receive them, and then process them.  This is not the paragon of efficiency.  It is *far* better to process millions of records close to the storage and so trade some CPU cost for for the others.

If you need something capable of more complex intraquery parallelism in a mixed or DW environment, go with Postgres-XC instead of vanilla PostgreSQL.  This has significant complexity cost, but in large environments makes otherwise unsolvable problems solvable.

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's begin with:

What will happen if you try to put a bucket of water in a glass??

That's all say that:

1. The first dependency is your database size.
2. Selecting millions of rows requires size of (millions * size of row) and hence require that many of Spool Space. The need for space is increased much if the Spool is further joined.
3. Those many rows will impact performance and make the query further slow if the database is not parallel aware and doesn't have a smart optimizer.

Anyhow, I think if you are dealing with millions/trillions of data you should consider moving to date warehouses like Teradata.